# acceptFileTypes Blueimp fileupload

Tags: jquery, regex, file-upload, blueimp

I have implemented JQuery fileupload, but have a small issue with the accepted file types:

```
$('#fileupload').
    url: '/upload/uploaddoc', // URL zum File Upload
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    uploadTemplate: 'template-upload',
    acceptFileTypes: /^.*\.(?!exe$|lnk$)[^.]+$/i,
    maxFileSize:allowed_file_size
    .......
 }
```

I am using a regex to recognize the filetypes that are not allowed. But I want to pass a variable that contains the accepted file types just like in the *maxFileSize* but it does not seem to accept lists and strings.

Do you know what is actually passed to acceptFileTypes ?

Comment: Did you try using `RegExp`? Say, `acceptFileTypes: new RegExp("^.*\\." + my_condition_lookahead + "[^.]+$", "i"),`?

Comment: it helped, i'll post my solution as an answer, so it may help also other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `RegExp` constructor.

Something like:

```
acceptFileTypes: new RegExp("^.*\\." + my_condition_lookahead + "[^.]+$", "i"),
```

Note that you need to double escape special regex meta characters when declaring a regex using constructor notation.

Answer (score 2):

the comment from stribizhev was helpful, I am creating the regex dinamically, this is my code:

```
NotallowedExtensions = ['.lnk', '.exe'];
for(var i= 0; i < NotallowedExtensions.length; i++){
    substr = NotallowedExtensions[i].substring(1);//i cut the (.) from the extension here
    if(i == NotallowedExtensions.length-1 ){
       regex+=substr + "$";
    } else {
      regex+=substr + "$|";
    }
}
```

after that my acceptFileTypes looks like this:

```
acceptFileTypes: new RegExp("^\.*\\.(?!" + regex + ")[^.]+$", "i")
```